# Probability of MIMI

Tags: probability

Mimi's restaurant is running a special promotion, Mimi gives out a prize ticket which has a 25% of chance of being a winning ticket. Customers who collect four winning lottery tickets are eligible for the “Special Dinner” a private party for 8 with selection of meal and wines. What is the probability of qualifying for the big spin if a customer fills up 7 times

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We want the probability of $4$ **or more** successes in $7$ independent trials, where the probability of success on any trial is $\frac{1}{4}$.